# Spring REST API + Spring security, блокируются api запросы

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, spring-security

помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.
Spring security блокирует api запросы к серверу.

Посылаю через Postman POST запрос по адресу "http://localhost:3245/api/homework", в теле данные в формате json
(id генерируется автоматически, "homework_user_id" - FK и имеет связь ManyToOne с главной таблицей)

```json
{
    "date": "19.05",
    "subject": "Алгебра",
    "homework": "с.80 №4,5",
    "homework_user_id": "9"
}
```

Получаю ответ:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2022-05-17T17:51:37.592+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/api/homework"
}
```

Реализация метода configure:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/leaper/timetable").hasRole("STUDENT")
                    .antMatchers("/leaper/homework").hasRole("STUDENT")
                    .antMatchers("/css/*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/*").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/leaper/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/leaper/timetable", true).permitAll();
    }
```

RestController(ко всем методам добавляется приставка "/api"):

```java
@PostMapping("/homework")
    public Homework addNewHomework(@RequestBody Homework homework) {
        homeworkService.saveHomework(homework);

        return homework;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил это в метод configure и всё заработало

```java
.csrf().disable()
```